# facebook instant article - showing page in ineligible

Tags: facebook-instant-articles

I am having Facebook page https://www.facebook.com/gossipserial/ 
2 months old and still it's showing ineligible.

I have even check some pages where FB instant article active and not 90 days old.

**bold I have tried to find out solution but not get any luck people are saying 90 days old required.. but why some pages facebook instant article showing before 90 days**

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not facebook's customer support

Comment: @Luuklag FYI this question I have posted with tag "Facebook-instant-articles" If someone has faced this issue while setup instant article than that can help me to set up and let me know the reason behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found that Facebook instant articles applied to 90 days old facebook page. Just a trick which I applied is like I pick old facebook page which I am not using and I rename that.